# Where is httpd serving content from if DocumentRoot is commented out in httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, document-root

Would love to know if there's a way to use some control utility to find it out. Doesn't seem like apachectl can do it, but maybe it can.

Edit: I should probably add that it's

```
root# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
root# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

and that the "default" DocumentRoot as specified by apache docs '' does not exist

```
# ls -la /usr/local/apache/htdocs
ls: cannot access /usr/local/apache/htdocs: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `DocumentRoot` is `"/usr/local/apache/htdocs"`, as specified by [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).

You may check if the `DocumentRoot` is specified by scanning all the apache conf files by bash:

```
grep -r "DocumentRoot" /etc/httpd

# or

grep -r "DocumentRoot" /etc/apache2
```